# How should I implement __eq__ and __hash__ if I want order independent equality

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class with a field named `arglist` whose value is a list.  I would like the order maintained to respect the callers provided order; however, I'd like equality to be independent  of order.

I have implemented the `__eq__` method as follows:

```py
    def __eq__(self, that):
        return type(self) is type(that) and \
            set(self.arglist) == set(that.arglist)
```

How should I now implement the `__hash__` method?  When I try to the following, I get a runtime error.

```py
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(set(self.arglist))
```

The error I get is

```
  File "/Users/jnewton/Repos/python-rte/genus/src/s_member.py", line 55, in __hash__
    return hash(set(self.arglist))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Maybe what I'm trying to do doesn't really make sense?   Do I need to give up on the idea of order-independent equality?

Comment: `set` is mutable. `hash` arguments must be immutable. Use a `frozenset` instead.

Comment: Do you want `Thing(1, 1, 2) == Thing(1, 2, 2)`? If not, you might need to use something like `collections.Counter` instead of `set` or `frozenset`.

Comment: Yes, I'm happy with `Thing(1,1,2)` being equal to `Thing(1,2,2)`

Comment: Also, if you want to allow mutable elements in `arglist`, you're going to have additional problems.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica,  What do you mean by "want to allow"?   Do I have a choice?   I'd love it if I could prevent mutability, but I was under the impression mutability was part of the Python philosophy, and you could not readily prevent users from sabotaging your data structures.

Comment: Not in terms of what you enforce, but in terms of what you consider supported use cases. (People can do all sorts of horrible things you never intended with your code and blame you when it doesn't work, and you can't stop that.) If your `==` implementation involves putting the elements of `arglist` into a set, then it's implicitly assuming that all elements of `arglist` are hashable. If there are any unhashable elements, your `==` will raise a TypeError. If you want to support unhashable elements in `arglist`, you may need a fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hash()` method in python only works with immutable data type but `set` is a mutable data type, hence it is throwing an error. A `frozenset` or `tuple` which are immutable could be used instead.

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

this might be of use to you :)

Comment: `dataclasses` doesn't offer anything useful for this.